# read in text file into matrix using built in functions

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to read a text file into a list of lists, the file looks like this:

```
x,x,1,x  
3,x,x,x  
x,x,x,1
```

Using the code below, I can only partially solve these issues, but not quite there yet.

```py
def grid_file(file_name):
file=[]
f=open(file_name)
for line in f:  
    line = line.split()
    file.append(line)
f.close()
return file
```

Expected result:

```
[ [‘x’,‘x’,1,‘x’], [4,‘x’,‘x’,‘x’], [‘x’,‘x’,‘x’,2], [‘x’,3,‘x’,‘x’] ]
```

Actual result:

```
[['x,x,1,x'], ['4,x,x,x'], ['x,x,x,2'], ['x,3,x,x']]
```

Comment: use `line.split(",")` or the `csv` module

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```py
def grid_file(file_name):
    file=[]
    f=open(file_name)
    for line in f.readlines():  
        line = line.split(",")
        file.append(line)
    f.close()
    return file
```